# How to pass Yii session to scripts out of Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

I have a self-made math captcha and it should be output without anything before it's image header, so I can't make it a 'View'. I put this captcha.php in the web root dir, but it can't share session with scripts in Yii. How to solve this?

Is there any way to pass the session from Yii to the other scripts or clean anything before the header in view?

Comment: Can you explain better why you can't make it a view? There should be no reason why something like this must be done outside the framework.

Comment: Yii will automatically add something in header like meta and script, and a picture cannot be output if there're anything before it's header that specifies this page should be displayed as an image

Comment: have you tried using $this->renderPartial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it is true that the default layout wraps the page's content with the typical html markup you'd expect, you have complete control over that by specifying the layout  you'd like from the controller by using `$this->layout = ...` You can set it to null to use module layout or false to disable the layout completely. See more details in [Yii API Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#layout-detail).

Alternatively you can call $this->renderPartial('view name') if you'd like the output of your captcha script displayed without the surrounding page content.